swift ExtensionFoundation/ExtensionKit in iOS
Is it possible to use ExtensionFoundation in iOS ?
Officially there is support but only a server side.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/extensionfoundation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/extensionkit
For example:
public protocol TextTransformExtension: AppExtension {
    
    /// Transform the input string according to your extension's behavior
    /// - Parameter input: The text entered by the user in TextTransformer.
    /// - Returns: The output that should be shown to the user, or `nil` if the transformation failed.
    func transform(_ input: String) async -> String?
}

/// Configuration for extensions that conform to the ``TextTransformExtension`` protocol.
public struct TextTransformExtensionConfiguration<E: TextTransformExtension>: AppExtensionConfiguration {
    let appExtension: E
    let server: TextTransformerExtensionXPCServer
    
    /// Creates a default configuration for the given extension.
    /// - Parameter appExtension: An instance of your custom extension that conforms to the ``TextTransformExtension`` protocol.
    public init(_ appExtension: E) {
        self.appExtension = appExtension
        self.server = TextTransformerExtensionXPCServer(with: appExtension)
    }
}

@_spi(TextTransformerSPI)
@objc public protocol TextTransformerXPCProtocol: NSObjectProtocol {
    func transform(input: String, reply: @escaping (String?) -> Void)
}

@objc final class TextTransformerExtensionXPCServer: NSObject, TextTransformerXPCProtocol {
    
    let implementation: any TextTransformExtension
    
    init(with implementation: some TextTransformExtension) {
        self.implementation = implementation
    }
    
    func transform(input: String, reply: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        Task {
            let result = await implementation.transform(input)
            await MainActor.run { reply(result) }
        }
    }
}

extension TextTransformExtensionConfiguration {
    public func accept(connection: NSXPCConnection) -> Bool {
        connection.exportedInterface = NSXPCInterface(with: TextTransformerXPCProtocol.self)
        connection.exportedObject = server
        
        connection.resume()
        
        return true
    }
}

but for connection we need to use something like
let process: AppExtensionProcess // only available on macOS let connection = try process.makeXPCConnection()
or
viewController.makeXPCConnection()
where viewController is EXHostViewController // only available on macOS
Is there any way to do it for iOS ? How to make a connection between iOS app and some app extension ?

There is no direct interprocess communication framework available for iOS. You can exchange information between your app and an extension via shared files, UserDefaults or keychain items.  Some extensions, such as widget extensions, have a specific method for notifying the extension of new data from the main app.
